# SharePoint 2013 upgrade ribbon bar grayed out and other control not working for admin with full control

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have migrated our SharePoint 2010 web app to SharePoint 2013 server in compatibility mode. This was working fine for few months. Now we did the upgrade of the site collection to 2013 mode by running through the UI wizard. This operation completed successfully.

But now

1. ribbon bar items (all) grayed out for the pages navigated from the settings page. for eg. site permissions page. We switched to OOB Seattle and Oslo master pages, but with the same issue.

[image: Grayed ribbon items for system account full control]

2. Also, the dropdown menu next to doc or list items won't open. or the box that displays site collection administrators in the add site collection administrator page is missing.

[image: no dropdown on list item click]

3. No site collection admin box.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is with web.config. Pages are forcing to 14.0 code base.